# trying to codesign a mac osx app but when I check it, I get `Pharo.app: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)`

Tags: macos, codesign

The issue is that codesign can not verify a signed app, it says that the Info.plist file has been modified, when in fact, it hasn't. I've even checked with `sha256sum` the file pre and post signing.

https://objective-see.com/products/whatsyoursign.html returns error code `-67030` which, according to https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/28/a-primer-on-code-signing-errors/ is due to

> invalid Info.plist, because the Info.plist file or its signature have been modified. That should never occur, and merits a close look to check what has happened. Although this property list is readily readable, its contents are complex and detecting deliberate tampering may not be easy.

Thing is, i've not modified the app in any way, I just sign it and then immediately check it's signature.

The application is a smalltalk vm found here: https://github.com/feenkcom/opensmalltalk-vm in the default branch.
to compile it one must

```
cmake .
make
make install
make package
```

and then in `build/packages` the first zip will contain Pharo.app

I unzip it and then run
`codesign --force -v --options=runtime  --deep --timestamp --file-list - -s $SIGNING_IDENTITY Pharo.app`

this works but then, if i run

`codesign --verify  --strict --verbose=2 Pharo.app`

i get lots of validated libraries (that is good) by also the error message that is also in the title `invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)`

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that codesign could not handle executable names starting with uppercase letters.
Once I changed the executable name to `pharo` instead of Pharo, it worked like magic.